# Activeadmin - Batch actions with parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Is any way to add customizable parameters for Batch action?

For example, i have this batch action:

```
batch_action :add_points do |ids|
  User.find(ids).each do |user|
    user.add_points "Some description", 10
  end
end
```

I need to make parameters for `add_points` customizable via popup or someone else.

Comment: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/6bde1f57ec5f9b724c21e5af146678f4ade839bc/lib/active_admin/batch_actions/views/batch_action_popover.rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution in the official documentation:

```
batch_action :add_points, form: {desc: :text, amount: :text} do |ids, inputs|
  User.find(ids).each do |user|
    user.add_points inputs['desc'], inputs['amount'].to_i
  end
end
```